# How can I make an authorization request based on the resource type through the Keycloak Java API?

Tags: java, resources, authorization, keycloak

I would like to be able to reproduce that behavior from the Keycloak UI using the Java Authorization API:
[image]

My goal with this is to get a list of all the resources a User can access for a specific resource type.
I have tested multiple things here.

This will give me a list of every resource one has access to. Although I'm afraid this won't scale very good.

```java
    AuthzClient authzClient = AuthzClient.create();
    AuthorizationResource authorizationResource = authzClient.authorization(keycloakSecurityContext.getTokenString());
    return authorizationResource.authorize().getToken();
```

This is what I use to get permissions on a specific scope.

```java
    AuthzClient authzClient = AuthzClient.create();
    AuthorizationResource authResource = authzClient.authorization(keycloakSecurityContext.getTokenString());
    AuthorizationRequest authRequest = new AuthorizationRequest();
    authRequest.addPermission(null, SCOPE1);
    authRequest.addPermission(null, SCOPE2);
    return authResource.authorize(authRequest).getToken();
```

However what I want is to do a request for a specific type and it seems that this is not possible.

I know I can list a specific type with:

```java
authzClient.protection().resource()
    .find(null,null,null,null, "The-Type-I-Want", null, false, 0, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
```

But again, this seems inappropriate cause it's not based on the user's permission and it will definitely not scale well if I tried to use it anyway.

So **how can I do a resource type authorization request ?**

Answer (score 1):

So I've found an alternate solution. It's not really answering the core question but it's answering the need behind this which is listing a set of resources of a specific type based on permissions.

I'm not using the type here. I have actually used a scope permission `AuthorizationRequest` as explained it the original question. What I changed is how things are configured on the keycloak side.

1. Create an Authorization Scope e.g. `myresourcetype:read`
2. Create a resource and set that scope on it.
3. Create a policy that reflects the conditions to access that resource
4. Create a resource-based permission using your policy and your scope.

Now if I do the following request:

```java
    AuthzClient authzClient = AuthzClient.create();
    AuthorizationResource authResource = authzClient.authorization(keycloakSecurityContext.getTokenString());
    AuthorizationRequest authRequest = new AuthorizationRequest();
    authRequest.addPermission(null, "myresourcetype:read");
    return authResource.authorize(authRequest).getToken();
```

I can expect the following kind of answer:

```json
    {
      [...],
      "authorization": {
        "permissions": [
          {
            "scopes": [
              "myresourcetype:read"
            ],
            "rsid": "f5466ba5-5c2c-4ec9-99f9-123d739f659c",
            "rsname": "myresource1"
          },
          {
            "scopes": [
              "myresourcetype:read"
            ],
            "rsid": "8ba2df8d-7274-48f2-a26a-edaa44c49c03",
            "rsname": "myresource2"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

This is not ideal as I would rather be able to get resources based on their actual type but for now that's the best I could come up with.